# How to get the records of last month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the records of last month based on my table [Sales], variable "SoldDate" in SQL Server.

For example, if today is 29/09/2021, I want to get the data for 01/08/2021-31/08/2021

The "SoldDate" variable is in the format 2018-04-11 00:00:00.000.

I would really appreciate your help! I have no idea how to get this to work :(

Comment: Is it a big table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: `datediff(month, SoldDate, getdate()) = 1` This is concise but not the best for searching in large, indexed databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [eomonth()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(SoldDate, -2)) AS StartDate, EOMONTH(SoldDate, -1) AS EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to search through an indexed table is to calculate what date range you need, and filter on that. You can use `DATEADD` and `EOMONTH` for this. Note that since you have a time component, you cannot just use `EOMONTH`

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE SoldDate >= DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2))
  AND SoldDate <  DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
```

- `EOMONTH` gives you the end of a month, the second parameter denotes how many months to shift.
- Note correct use of the half-open interval `>= AND <`, this dealls correctly with the time component.

Comment: Of course you need to compute relative to the date parameter, in this case current day.

Comment: Whoops fixed that now